# Passing data with prepareForSegue doesn't work

Tags: swift

I am using the MapKit and when you click on an annotation balloon you get directed to another view. The function I am using for this is:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    //get tag here
    if(annotationView.tag == 0){
        //Do for 0 pin
    }

    if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("mapToCity", sender: self)
    }
}
```

But the problem is that I can't pass the marker data to the next view. I tried using this function in the first view but I don't exactly know how to retrieve the data in the next view or if it is even saved in "CityDetails":

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "mapToCity") {

        var yourNextViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as! CityDetails)
    }
}
```

In the second viewcontroller this:

```
println(CityDetails);
```

Only returns the location of CityDetails which is in my case `Ontdek_Polen.CityDetails`

Comment: Where is `CityDetails`?

Comment: CityDetails is an alias of segue.destinationViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use segue to pass data from one view to another view then use this code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "mapToCity") {

        var yourNextViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CityDetails
        yourNextViewController.foo = "This is passed"
    }
}
```

In your destination view don't forget to create an instance which will hold this value like this:

```
import UIKit

class CityDetails: UIViewController {

    var foo = ""         //this will  hold your value

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println(foo)    //This is passed
    }

}
```

Don't forget to set the type of your instance in next view same as you want to pass from previous view.

And one more way to pass data from one view to another view is you can use `NSUserDefaults` as shown in below example:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    //get tag here
    if(annotationView.tag == 0){
        //Do for 0 pin
    }

    if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        //set your object here
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("abcd", forKey: "yourKey")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("mapToCity", sender: self)
    }
}
```

This will store this value into disk so you can read this value anywhere into your project with `yourKey`.

This way you can read value from `NSUserDefault`:

```
import UIKit

class CityDetails: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let foo1 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("yourKey") as! String
        println(foo1)       //abcd
    }
}
```

And for more [Info](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=02355878999677430565) check THIS sample project where I am passing value with segue.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot this works the way I want it. But how do I retrieve the information of the marker that I clicked on? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: You want location on map where you clicked?

Comment: And don't forget to accept the answer if it helps..:)

Comment: I want to send the title, subtitle, and coordinates of the marker to the next map. Or perhaps just the id of the marker so I can call it again.

Comment: which way you want I mean `NSUserDefaults` way or segue way?

Comment: Both are fine but I find the segue way more convenient. And I feel like NSUserDefaults is something like sessions or cookies which I rather not use for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85296/discussion-between-dharmesh-kheni-and-sinan-samet).

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use the code `(segue.destinationViewController as! CityDetails)`.

What I would recommend doing is instead of using the last bit of code to access the destination view controllers items just create an instance of the class and access its variables and data through dot notation.

ex. (in this example I am saying that the name of the destination vc is CityDetails)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "mapToCity") {

        var yourNextViewController: CityDetails = CityDetails()
        yourNextViewController.variable = 0 //example

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this looks a lot more clear. But is there a way to send the marker data along when I click the balloon?

Comment: yup, all you would do is transfer the data using the line of code that I stated above `yourNextViewController.variable = ` and then after the equal you just pass the marker data which I assume is an annotation and you have to make sure that the type of data variable that you are passing it to is of the same type

Comment: I just noticed that it always returns nil whatever I use for "variable"

Comment: That means the variable you are passing in is nil, you are doing something wrong before the segue

Comment: Do I need to replace the variable "yourNextViewController" to something else? Because the name of my next viewcontroller is CityDetails. Sorry I'm probably making a stupid mistake I'm new with Swift

Comment: No worries, you are creating a variable/instance of the view controller CityDetails.  `yourNextViewController` just is a way to access your CityDetails attributes once you have declared it.

Comment: But how does it return nil? In the first view I used this `yourNextViewController.subtitle = "Test"` and I print it in the second one as this `println(subtitle);` So that should just work right? I copied your function in the first view. And I declared the variable as `var subtitle:String?`